# gdb reports wrong ELF version even though library matches gdb filetype?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, elf, 32-bit

So I'm trying to debug some code with gdb, I've got a 32-bit environment installed on a 64-bit OS (Ubuntu18), everything compiles/links correctly....

I run the binary, it executes, works, no problems.

I try to run it using gdb - the following happens:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/src/Duris/dms
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
During startup program exited with code 127.
```

All of the files/libraries involved seem to be the correct 32-bit version... so what exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
obr@melbourne:/usr/src/Duris$ file dms
dms: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=fdf6e191894c459ebb5abe9287841eafdc858fa5, with debug_info, not stripped
obr@melbourne:/usr/src/Duris$ file /usr/bin/gdb
/usr/bin/gdb: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=fd1c820fe9165e82c09af64b7dd4ae728347a179, stripped
obr@melbourne:/usr/src/Duris$ file /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5
/usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5: symbolic link to /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
obr@melbourne:/usr/src/Duris$ file /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=adf5caf5c1be713bfc7846377c08b3164ffa50ea, stripped
obr@melbourne:/usr/src/Duris$
```

Any advice?

Comment: If you run `/bin/bash` from your shell - not from GDB - do you also get that shared library error?

Comment: Too late to check now, I reinstalled the whole server... I'm working on converting the code to run natively as 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

> what exactly am I doing wrong here?

You have set up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in such a way that 32-bit `libtinfo.so.5` is found before 64-bit one.

When you run a 32-bit `dms` binary, it runs fine.

But GDB *doesn't* run the `dms` binary directly. Instead it invokes `bash -c dms`, and has `bash` handle input/output redirection (if any).

However, the 64-bit `bash` binary *also* depends on `libtinfo.so.5`, and when *it* finds the 32-bit version, it complains with the error you are getting: `/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: wrong ELF class...`.

Note in particular that the error is from `/bin/bash`, *not* from `dms`.

---

There are a few possible solutions:

- stop setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or at least including `/lib/i386-linux-gnu` in it -- the 32-bit dynamic loader should look in `/lib/i386-linux-gnu` *automatically*.
- use `set startup-with-shell off` GDB command ([documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html)) before running the binary from GDB.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I voted you up - I've already rewritten the code so it works natively in 64-bit mode now... I got sick of messing around with both 32-bit and 64-bit packages and constant dependency errors from apt and aptitude.